# Pass onClick event to TanStack Table

Tags: next.js, tanstack-table

I'm working on creating a table component using NextJS and TanStack Table. Currently, I have a component that serves as the foundation for the TanStack Table. I pass the respective ColumnDef of the page and the data to be displayed into this component. In other words, depending on the page I visit, different data is fed into the TanStack Table.

This is working well so far. Now, I want to include a method for an onClick event for each page. For example, Page 1 should receive onRowClicked1, and Page 2 should receive onRowClicked2.

Whats the best way of doing it? I tried to pass the function from the parent component to the TableComponent but is this the best way?

Thanks!

This is my TableComponent:

```
import {
  ColumnDef,
  ColumnFiltersState,
  SortingState,
  VisibilityState,
  flexRender,
  getCoreRowModel,
  getFilteredRowModel,
  getPaginationRowModel,
  getSortedRowModel,
  useReactTable,
} from "@tanstack/react-table";
import React, { useState } from "react";

interface DataTableProps<TData, TValue> {
  columns: ColumnDef<TData, TValue>[];
  data: TData[];
}

export function DataTable<TData, TValue>({
  columns,
  data,
}: DataTableProps<TData, TValue>) {
  const [sorting, setSorting] = useState<SortingState>([]);
  const [columnFilters, setColumnFilters] = useState<ColumnFiltersState>([]);
  const [columnVisibility, setColumnVisibility] = useState<VisibilityState>({});

  const table = useReactTable({
    data,
    columns,
    state: {
      sorting,
      columnFilters,
      columnVisibility,
    },
    onSortingChange: setSorting,
    onColumnFiltersChange: setColumnFilters,
    onColumnVisibilityChange: setColumnVisibility,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    getSortedRowModel: getSortedRowModel(),
    getFilteredRowModel: getFilteredRowModel(),
    getPaginationRowModel: getPaginationRowModel(),
  });

  return (
    <>
      <div className="rounded-md border">
        <table className="border border-gray-700 w-full text-left">
          <thead className="bg-indigo-600">
            {table.getHeaderGroups().map((headerGroup) => (
              <tr key={headerGroup.id}>
                {headerGroup.headers.map((header) => (
                  <th key={header.id} className="capitalize px-3.5 py-2">
                    {flexRender(
                      header.column.columnDef.header,
                      header.getContext()
                    )}
                  </th>
                ))}
              </tr>
            ))}
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {table.getRowModel().rows.length ? (
              table.getRowModel().rows.map((row, i) => (
                <tr
                  key={row.id}
                  className={`
                ${i % 2 === 0 ? "bg-gray-900" : "bg-gray-800"}
                `}
                >
                  {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => (
                    <td key={cell.id} className="px-3.5 py-2" onClick={() => console.log(row.original.id)}>
                      {flexRender(
                        cell.column.columnDef.cell,
                        cell.getContext()
                      )}
                    </td>
                  ))}
                </tr>
              ))
            ) : (
              <tr className="text-center h-32">
                <td colSpan={12}>No Recoard Found!</td>
              </tr>
            )}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```